# Change file association in High Sierra (NOT command I)

Tags: file-association, macos-highsierra

I changed the file association for my .dvdmedia files on my Mac to point at Blu-ray Player Pro. As it turns out this was a mistake as it turned all the .dvdmedia files into plain directories. Google has shown me the usual cmd-I solution (which doesn't work because what were bundles are being viewed as directories because of the file association on .dvdmedia) and some outdated advice to try duti which unfortunately doesn't compile on High Sierra (and might not work at all, who knows?).

Presumably, there's some way to fix this by editing a plist somewhere, but I've not found it yet. I did find that logging in as a different user showed the files correctly. Any thoughts on how to undo my gross mistake?